# Overlapping periods value summary on chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I don't know what I'm looking for maybe that is why I can't find solution online.

Just trying to show a data on simple chart with time axis.

Example of data I have:

| ID | StartTime | EndTime | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 10 |
| 2 | 11:30:00 | 12:20:00 | 10 |
| 3 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 10 |
| 4 | 13:40:00 | 14:00:00 | 10 |
| 5 | 13:50:00 | 15:00:00 | 10 |

Now on chart I would like to show:

| Axis | Value on Chart |
| --- | --- |
| 11:00:00 | 10 |
| 11:15:00 | 10 |
| 11:30:00 | 20 |
| 11:45:00 | 20 |
| 12:00:00 | 20 |
| 12:15:00 | 20 |
| 12:30:00 | 10 |
| 12:45:00 | 10 |
| ... | ... |

So overlapping period values should show on chart as sum.
Axis interval 15 min is just for example, but if required it could be fixed to 10 or 15 minutes.

Comment: I would work with a helper column that matches start/end time to the values you want on the axis.

Comment: I do have table in model with values for axis and I assume I would have to merge those to somehow to create multiple entries for each start-end time, one for each axis period, but have no clue how to do it in model it self. In SQL it would be simple join if start <  timestamp < endtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PQ M code you could:

- Create a list of ALL the 15 minute bins from the earliest Start to the Latest end
- Create a list of the 15 minute bins for each row Start..End
- Join the two with `JoinType.FullOuter`
- Group by the bin, return the Sum for each interval and Sort

**Source**
[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTI0tDIwACIQ0wjBNFCK1YlWMoIoMEYoMEJVYIymzRjdBBOIqAlM1ARdgSlEgSlM1BRFQSwA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, StartTime = _t, EndTime = _t, Quantity = _t]),

//set data types 
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"StartTime", type time}, {"EndTime", type time}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}}),

//create List of all 15 minute intervals from earliest Start time to latest End time
    quarterHours = List.Times(
            List.Min(#"Changed Type"[StartTime]), 
            Duration.TotalMinutes(
                List.Max(#"Changed Type"[EndTime]) - List.Min(#"Changed Type"[StartTime]))/15,#duration(0,0,15,0)),

//compute a List of 15 minute bins for each row
// where Start Time is rounded down to the 15 minute interval; and End Time is rounded up to the 15 minute interval
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Time Bin", 
        each List.Transform(
            {Number.RoundDown(Number.From([StartTime])*96,0)..Number.RoundUp(Number.From([EndTime])*96,0)-1},
                each _/96)),

//expand the Time Bin list to one entry per 15 minute interval
//and set the data type
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Time Bin"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Time Bin", type time}}),

//Join the column that has ALL of the 15 minute bins (so as to account for those intervals with no entries
    addAllTimes = Table.Join(#"Changed Type1","Time Bin",
        Table.FromColumns({quarterHours},type table[Bin=Time.Type]),"Bin",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//Group by Bin and Sort by time
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(addAllTimes, {"Bin"}, {{"Quantity", each List.Sum([Quantity]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Bin", Order.Ascending}})
    
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

**Results**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a new table corresponding to the Axis column you show and then write a measure to use for the values along these lines:

```
ChartValue =
VAR CurrTime = SELECTEDVALUE ( NewTable[Axis] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Data[Amount] ),
        Data[StartTime] <= CurrTime,
        Data[EndTime] >= CurrTime
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example I put the data from your question into a table (insert > table) and named it tblData.

The axis-data are in table tblAxis, Quantity is calculated using the the SUMIFS-Formula which checks for Start and End-Time.

`=SUMIFS(tblData[Quantity];tblData[StartTime];"<=" & [@Axis];tblData[EndTime];">" & [@Axis])`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both.

Both solutions works!!

However for my limited knowledge, makes it easier for me to use ike solutions.

Comment: Not an answer it's a comment